# customizing the number of digits in exponent in boost multiprecision

Tags: c++, boost-serialization, boost-multiprecision

We've just migrated to Visual Studio 2017 and due to the [change described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344(v=vs.140).aspx) the serialized output of a double value using `std::scientific` does not carry anymore 2 digits in the exponent but only one.

```
 BEOFRE: 5.49000000000000000e+002
 NOW   : 5.49000000000000000e+02
```

We use `boost::serialization` to serialize to XML.

We were thinking to switch to `boost::multiprecision` to handle bigger number, but still we have to fix this issue with the digits in the exponent.

Is there any way to get back to the old notation 'e+002' or even customize it with `boost::multiprecision` ?

Comment: quote: "C requires that if the exponent is representable using only one or two digits, then only two digits are to be printed." - the number of digits in the exponent varies anyway on the size of the number. maybe you try to solve a problem on the wrong side. what is the reason for requireing 2 digits?

Comment: What happens when the exponent is bigger , e+20 (2^70) or e+200 (2^700)? I assume it works correctly? Does your xml really care, or are you trying to preserve your regression test cases?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: for big numbers works fine. I was just trying to find an easy way to continue supporting the old way of outputting doubles with e+002

Answer (score 0):

Reading the relevant section, it appears that _set_output_format with not _TWO_DIGIT_EXPONENT might give the old behaviour?

> Exponent formatting The %e and %E format specifiers format a floating point number as a decimal mantissa and exponent. The %g and %G format specifiers also format numbers in this form in some cases. In previous versions, the CRT would always generate strings with three-digit exponents. For example, printf("%e\n", 1.0) would print 1.000000e+000. This was incorrect: C requires that if the exponent is representable using only one or two digits, then only two digits are to be printed.
>
> In Visual Studio *2005* a global conformance switch was added: **_set_output_format**. A program could call this function with the argument **_TWO_DIGIT_EXPONENT**, to enable conforming exponent printing. The ***default*** behavior has been changed to the standards-conforming exponent printing mode.

Comment: what you are saying is correct. I read the same..problem is that I can't find neither _set_output_format nor _TWO_DIGIT_EXPONENT  anywhere in Visual Studio 2017...though given the name it seems that this function was put in place to go fom e+003 to +002..  What I need is possibly the old behavior.